Independence of two functions
Assume that f is a continuous function over the interval $[a,b]$ and there exists $x \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$. I want to show that $f(x)$ and $xf(x)$ are linearly independent on this interval.
$\textbf{My attempt:}$
Assume to the contrary that these two functions are linearly dependent. Then there exists $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(c_1, c_2) \neq (0,0)$ such that
$$c_1 f(x) + c_2 xf(x) = 0$$
$$\implies f(x) (c_1 + c_2 x) = 0$$
Assume $f(x_1) \neq 0, x_1 \in [a,b]$, then
$$f(x_1) (c_1 + c_2 x_1) = 0$$
$$ \implies c_1 + c_2 x_1 = 0 \implies x_1 = -\dfrac{c_1}{c_2}$$
But unfortunately, I could not go beyond and obtain a contradiction. Is my starting point correct, and I did not use $f$'s being continuous at all? Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Suppose that there exists real numbers $c_1$ and $c_2$ not both zero, such that
$$\tag{1}\label{1}
c_1 f(x) + c_2 x f(x) = 0
$$
For all $x \in [a,b]$.
Let $\alpha \in [a,b]$ such that $f(\alpha) \neq 0$. Because of continuity there exists an open neighborhood (respect to $[a,b]$) $U$ of $\alpha$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in U$. Furthermore there exists $x_0 \in U$ with $x_0 \neq 0$ such that $f(x_0) \neq 0$ (this is possible due to any real open subset is uncountable). By our hypothesis
$$
c_1 f(x_0) + c_2 x_0 f(x_0) = 0
$$
so $f(x_0) =0$ or $c_1 + c_2 x_0 = 0$. Of course $f(x_0) = 0$ is not true, then we have $c_1  + c_2 x_0 = 0$. If $c_2 =0$ then $c_1=0$. Hence $c_2 \neq 0$, which implies $x_0 = -\frac{c_1}{c_2}$ and $c_1 \neq 0$ by our assumption about $x_0$. But because $U$ is open there exists nonzero $x' \in U$ with $x' \neq x_0$ such that $f(x') \neq 0$ and $x'$ doesn't satisfy the equality \eqref{1}. Wich is a contradiction.
